# How to convert string to int in linq to entity?

Tags: string, casting, integer, linq-to-entities

```
var trnlist = from tr in db.DebtorTransactions
                              join wr in db.Warranties
                      on  tr.ProductID equals Convert.ToInt32(wr.PkfWarranty) into wrtd 
                              from wr1 in db.Warranties
                              join sr in db.SalesReps
                              on wr1.fldSrId equals sr.pkfSrID into wrsr
                              from wr2 in db.Warranties
                              join ag in db.Agentsenter code here
                              on wr2.fldAgentID equals ag.pkfAgentID into wrag
                              select wrtd;
```

`tr.ProductID` is an int and `wr.PKfWarranty` is string.`var rustul= convert.toint32(tr.ProductID)` doesn't suitable for me.

Is there any built-in function of Linq to entity to do this?

Comment: `var ints = strings.Select(x => int.Parse(x));`

Comment: no sir ..its not working

Comment: the error is "the best overload method match for int.parse(string) has some invalid arguments"

Comment: i have tried wr.PkfWarranty.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())) but still its not working

Comment: Please look at this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245882/linq-2-entities-performing-a-join-on-two-columns-with-different-types

Comment: This is the same as [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694716/entity-framework-linq-expression-converting-from-string-to-int/24027242#24027242][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694716/entity-framework-linq-expression-converting-from-string-to-int/24027242#24027242

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you say:

> tr.ProductID is a int

And then you try:

> convert.toint32(tr.ProductID)

So... you're trying to convert an `int` to an `int`?  In a comment you say:

> the best overload method match for int.parse(string) has some invalid arguments

Well, if you're trying to call `int.Parse()` and passing it an `int` then you'd probably get that exact error.  I imagine there's no overload for `int.Parse()` which accepts an `int` since, well, the value is already an `int`.

Let's look back at your problem description:

> tr.ProductID is a int and wr.PKfWarranty is String

And you want to compare these two values?  Then you'll either need to convert `tr.ProductID` to a `string`:

```
tr.ProductID.ToString()
```

*or* convert `wr.PKfWarranty` to an `int`:

```
int.Parse(wr.PKfWarranty)
```

A few things to note:

- Converting from an `int` to a `string` is pretty safe, I doubt you'll ever have problems with that.  However, converting from a `string` to an `int` *assumes* that the string *can be* converted to an `int`.  This won't be the case if the string has anything in it that's not an `int`, or has a number too large to fit into the `int` data type.  `int.TryParse()` exists for this purpose, but can be tricky to use in an in-line LINQ statement, especially when that statement is an expression tree which needs to produce SQL code.
- If you convert the `int` to a `string`, there are different ways to compare strings.  Depending on whether this is happening in resulting SQL code or in C# code makes a difference.  If the latter, `string.Equals()` is the preferred method.

Comment: I didnt read all the explanation, I converted the second value being compared to Int (Thanks to you) and it worked.